# Galaxy S3: Broadcastreceiver does not receive anything. Works with any other phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, galaxy

I have a plugin that is has to receive a Broadcast. The declaration in the manifest is as followed:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Receiver"
    android:permission="de.bulling.smstalkvc_offline.permission.RECEIVE" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="de.bulling.smstalkvc_offline.ISINSTALLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The main app and the plugin have the permissions declared in the manifest:

```
<permission
    android:name="de.bulling.smstalkvc_offline.permission.RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="de.bulling.smstalkvc_offline.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I checked with the PackageManager class and **both apps do have the permission granted** (and just to double check, Android also says it is the same signature).

*However* the receiver doesn't receive anything. Because this happens on the Galaxy S3 only, it has to be a problem with the device. Any advice how to fix this, or at least any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using am broadcast using adb shell to test?